# Menu specific to mobile version

Tags: html, mobile, navigation

how are you?

I'm a little problem. I have a project that contains some navigations (they are not grouped).

In mobile version, I want there to be only one navigation.

I will go add all itens in a separated navigation with "aria-hidden: true" (showing just in mobile) and others navigations hidden in mobile version.

This alternative is semantic?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have almost no idea what you're asking. I get the impression you want to show only one navigation menu if viewed on a mobile device, but allow for show all navigation elements in a desktop  setting? For this, if it's possible, we'd need to know whether you need to use [tag:css], [tag:javascript] or a server-side solution. Also, what (relevant/[sscce](http://sscce.org/)) HTML do you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

IMO

`@media` tag is suitable for the situation.

You can decide based on screen size and media type what you want to display. Read more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)